# Programmatically creating an ios genius playlist

Tags: ios, ipod, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm looking for a way to create programmatically a genius playlist based on a random song.

Something like:
1.- pick a random song from ipod library
2.- query genius for 25 songs related to the random song picked 
3.- make MPMusicPlayerController play all the created playlist

All I have found is an attribute called "MPMediaPlaylistAttributeGenius" [1]. I think it allows to look for a previously created genius playlist.

thanks

[1]= http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlaylist_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to create your own genius playlists programmatically because Apple does not provide a method for doing so. They only allow you to search for previously created genius playlists by creating an MPMediaQuery, filtering by Playlists, then filtering by the attribute "MPMediaPlaylistAttributeGenius".